# Added template map dynamic in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I must hard code to add new layout. Then i want find some way to add template map dynamic in ZF2.

My module.config.php

```
'view_manager' => array (
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    'doctype' => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
    'exception_template' => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array (
            'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/layout/layout.phtml',
            'layout/custom' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/layout/custom.phtml',
            'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../../../template/error/index.phtml' 
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array (
            __DIR__ . '/../view/'
    ) 
)
```

And I set new layout by this way

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $controller->layout('template_name');
}, 100);
```

Please lets me some advise/sample

Thanks !

==================

Update 12/08/2012:

I found the solution for this and apply to my "hierarchy template system"

Modify module.config.php

```
'template_path_stack' => array (
     __DIR__ . '/../view/',
 __DIR__ . '/../../../' //Parent folder of template path
)
```

In Module.php added :

```
$e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    $controllerClass = get_class($controller);


    //Get routing info
    $controllerArr = explode('\\', $controllerClass);
    $currentRoute = array(
        'module' =>  strtolower($controllerArr[0]),
        'controller' => strtolower(str_replace("Controller", "", $controllerArr[2])),
        'action' => strtolower($controller->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action'))
    );


    //Get curr route
    $currAction = implode('/',$currentRoute);
    $currController = $currentRoute['module'] . '/' . $currentRoute['controller'];
    $currModule = $currentRoute['module'];



    //Template file location
    $templatePath = __DIR__ .'/../../template/';

    //Set template
    $template = 'layout/layout'; // Default template

    if (file_exists($templatePath . $currAction.'.phtml')) {
        $template = $currAction;
    }else if(file_exists($templatePath . $currController.'.phtml')) {
        $template = $currController;
    }else if(file_exists($templatePath . $currModule.'.phtml')) {
        $template = $currModule;
    }else{
        if($currentRoute['controller']=='admin'){
            $template = 'admin/layout'; // Admin default template
        }
    }

    $controller->layout('template/'.$template); //Pevert duplicate layout
}, 100);
```

Note: If you set the key same variable between your 'layout' and 'view'. It will render duplicate the 'layout' and don't understand your current view

Comment: Hi, you want to make 'template_name' variable? like based on the name of the domain/website?

Comment: Yeah. I want to make new row in 'template_name' base on current module/controller/view. Then i want find some way to add it without hard code in module.config.php

Answer (score 0):

In your controller when you create a new viewmodel you can set the template you've created there.

```
public function someAction() {
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/custom');

    return $viewModel;
}
```

Just make sure the layout.phtml file is in the path you set in your template_map

Comment: Thanks! But i mean i want to add new "template_map" without hard code in module.config.php

Comment: I understand what you want, I think I am dealing with the same thing. One application, couple of websites used the same controller but different layout and view for each website.

Comment: Hmm not for the website but that's a good idea too. I want something like "wordpress template hierarchy" http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy . You can overwrite template base on current module/controller/action

Comment: So you're looking for more a theme engine type way of changing the template?  That's going to be a little tricky.  You could have a bare bones main application layout then have a template that would act as a theme and piece together you site with sub-templates.